# Comparing a K-means scatterplot to ground truth scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, k-means

I have a dataset with x and y variables. There is also a z column which specifies what group x and y belong to. There are 11 groups. I have used K-means clustering to create a machine that will assort the x and y variables into the correct groups. I have then plotted those x and y variables onto a scatter plot and K-means has assorted them into one of 11 unique colours. I now want to compare that to the ground truth (which in this case are the original x and y variables). I want it to be represented on a 3rd scatterplot which will highlight in red the data points that K-means produced which does not correspond to the ground truth and will highlight in green the ones that do.

How can I code this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans  
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("FILENAME")
 print(df)

x = df['height_mean']
y = df['weight_mean']

points = df[['height_mean', 'weight_mean']].values

#np.array([Values here])

# Number of clusters
n_clusters = 11

# Fit the KMeans model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
kmeans.fit(points)

# Get cluster assignments
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Get cluster centers
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# Plot the clusters
plt.scatter(x, y, c=labels, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='red', marker='x', s=100)  # Plot cluster centers    as red X's
plt.xlabel('height')
plt.ylabel('weight')
plt.title("K-Means Clustering")

plt.show()
print(df)`
```

This is the k-means scatterplot. How do I modify this to compare it to the ground truth scatterplot?

Comment: Please review #3 & #9 of [Creating Effective Stack Overflow Questions](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/Creating_Effective_StackOverflow_Questions.html) and [edit] the question. This lacks a complete [mre].

Answer (score 0):

To compare the K-means cluster assignments with the ground truth (specified in the 'z' column), you can create a new scatter plot where points are colored based on whether the K-means label matches the ground truth. Here's a code example based on the code you provided:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans  
import pandas as pd

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("FILENAME")
print(df)

# Extract data
x = df['height_mean']
y = df['weight_mean']
z = df['group_column_name']  # Replace 'group_column_name' with the actual name of the column that specifies the group

points = df[['height_mean', 'weight_mean']].values

# Number of clusters
n_clusters = 11

# Fit the KMeans model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
kmeans.fit(points)

# Get cluster assignments
labels = kmeans.labels_

# Create an array to store colors for each point
colors = np.zeros(labels.shape, dtype=str)

# Compare with ground truth
for i in range(len(labels)):
    if labels[i] == z[i]:
        colors[i] = 'g'  # Green for a match
    else:
        colors[i] = 'r'  # Red for a mismatch

# Plot the clusters
plt.scatter(x, y, c=labels, cmap='viridis', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, alpha=0.5)  # Overplot points with the color array to show matches/mismatches
plt.xlabel('height')
plt.ylabel('weight')
plt.title("K-Means Clustering vs Ground Truth")

plt.show()
```

- The `z` array represents the ground truth for each point.
- We create a `colors` array that will store a color ('g' for green or 'r' for red) for each point.
- We then loop through the K-means labels and ground truth labels to populate the `colors` array. A point will be colored green if the K-means label matches the ground truth, and red otherwise.
- Finally, we plot the points with the colors specified in the `colors` array.